# Why is it written in nmap official doc that -sL does not send any packet, when it actually send them?

Tags: networking, security, firewall, wireshark, nmap

Sniffing with wireshark, I see a bunch of ARP, and DNS requests.
So why in the official doc it's written this:

> The list scan is a degenerate form of host discovery that simply lists
> each host of the network(s) specified, without sending any packets to
> the target hosts. By default, Nmap still does reverse-DNS resolution
> on the hosts to learn their names. It is often surprising how much
> useful information simple hostnames give out. For example, fw.chi is
> the name of one company's Chicago firewall. Nmap also reports the
> total number of IP addresses at the end. The list scan is a good
> sanity check to ensure that you have proper IP addresses for your
> targets. If the hosts sport domain names you do not recognize, it is
> worth investigating further to prevent scanning the wrong company's
> network.
>
> Since the idea is to simply print a list of target hosts, options for higher level functionality such as port scanning, OS detection, or
> host discovery cannot be combined with this. If you wish to disable
> host discovery while still performing such higher level functionality,
> read up on the -Pn (skip host discovery) option.

Source: [Host Discovery | Nmap Network Scanning](https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html)

Comment: Does it send all those packets _to the target hosts?_

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/759732/why-is-it-written-in-nmap-official-doc-that-sl-does-not-send-any-packet-when-i

Answer (score 0):

The documentation could be a bit clearer...

-sL doesn't send any probe packets to each host (to check for open ports/running services), but still does the basic ping-based network scan to find the hosts. (How else is it to discover what is on the network?).

ARP and ICMP are part of that ping-based scan. (Ping is a form of ICMP and ARP is needed to determine the mac-address that goes with an ip-address so it  usually preceeds the actual ping.)
The DNS queries are made to resolve the ip-adresses found into hostnames (as mentioned in the documentation "reverse-DNS resolution").

Comment: sorry, it turns out icmp packets are not created by nmap, they must come from other source. anyway, if it should only do a reverse-DNS resolution, why does it send arp requests? in the doc it's literally written "it does not send packet to targets".... but nmaps sends an ARP requests to each of the hosts specified in nmap command (I gave in input a /24 subnet), so it actually "talks" with the target, since the targets will respond to the ARP request